# SharpZipLib's FastZip doesn't unzip directories on Mac

Tags: mono, sharpziplib, fastzip

I'm using the following code on Mac using Mono to unzip a zip file. The zip file contains entries under directories (for example `foo/bar.txt`). However, in the unzipped directory, instead of creating a directory `foo` with a file `bar.txt`, FastZip creates a file `foo\bar.txt`. How do I get around this?

```
FastZip fz = new FastZip();
string filePath = @"path\to\myfile.zip";

fz.ExtractZip(filePath, @"path\to\unzip\to", null);
```

This creates a file `foo\bar.txt` in `path\to\unzip\to`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently cannot use `FastZip` for this case so I ended up writing my own unzipping mechanism:

```
string filePath = @"path\to\myfile.zip";
string unzipDir = @"path\to\unzip\to";

using (var zipFile = new ZipFile(filePath))
{
    foreach (var zipEntry in zipFile.OfType<ZipEntry>())
    {
        var unzipPath = Path.Combine(unzipDir, zipEntry.Name);
        var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(unzipPath);

        // create directory if needed
        if (directoryPath.Length > 0)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
        }

        // unzip the file
        var zipStream = zipFile.GetInputStream(zipEntry);
        var buffer = new byte[4096];

        using (var unzippedFileStream = File.Create(unzipPath))
        {
            StreamUtils.Copy(zipStream, unzippedFileStream, buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you might also want to check if its an dir : `if(!zipEntry.IsDirectory) { //unzip stream `. Otherwise dir in zipfile will create an error.

Answer (score -1):

use a forward slash to separate folders when creating the zip

Comment: We don't control zip creation.

Comment: You don't really need to downgrade me for this... it could help someone else who *does* have control of the zip file.